# proper location of memcached custom seralizer jars

Tags: java, tomcat, memcached, tomcat7

The memcached documentation instructs the base libraries go into $CATALINA_HOME/lib/ and that any custom serialization libraries go into WEB-APP/lib.

We have many webapps running on the Tomcat (v7) instance.  is there any reason we can't/shouldn't just put all of the jar file in $CATALINA_HOME/lib/ so we don't have to replicate the jars in each webapp?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you wouldn't want to do that is it forces every application to use the same version of the JAR. If you ever need one of the apps to be behind the others and use an older version (because it's not updated or it can't be updated yet), this would cause issues.

On the other hand, the only downside to having multiple versions of the same JAR spread around the `WEB-INF/lib` of multiple applications on the same server is the wasted disk space, which I would imagine in most cases is only dozens of KBs and not really all that much of a "waste" in the end.